# ReferenceError: Cannot access 'heap' before initialization

Tags: javascript, webpack, rust, wasm-bindgen

I am trying to use a wasm compiled from rust bundled with webpack. I have this simple js file that I load in my index.html head:

**example-project/src/index.js**:

```js
document.addEventListener('readystatechange', async () => {
    if (document.readyState !== 'complete') return;

    const rust = await import('@webline/webline-core');
    rust.greet_async(console.log);
});
```

But I get this error when I navigate to index.html (served with `http-serve`):

```
ReferenceError: Cannot access 'heap' before initialization
    at Module.greet_async (webline_core_bg.js:77)
    at eval (index.js:9)
```

*Chrome Dev Tools Sources > index.js*

```js
document.addEventListener('readystatechange', () => {
    if (document.readyState !== 'complete') return;

    rust = __webpack_require__ //.. webpack code omitted here, ignore
    rust.then(m => m.greet_async(console.log))
//                   ^^^^^^^^^^^ <- index.js:9 error here
        .catch(console.error);
});
```

*Chrome Dev Tools Sources > webline_core_bg.js*

```js
// (omitted code)...
function greet_async(f) {
    try {
        _webline_core_bg_wasm__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.greet_async(addBorrowedObject(f));
    } finally {
        heap[stack_pointer++] = undefined;
//      ^^^^ <- webline_core_bg.js:77 error here
//                heap is defined on line 34 of the same file as: 
//                const heap = new Array(32).fill(undefined);
    }
}
// ...(omitted code)
```

How do I fix this?

#### Project information:

`@webline/webline-core` is a local npm package that I added using `npm link "@webline/webline-core". It has a simple rust file that I adapted from the [hello-world tutorial](https://rustwasm.github.io/docs/wasm-bindgen/examples/hello-world.html):

**webline-core/src/lib.rs**:

```rust
use wasm_bindgen::prelude::*;

#[wasm_bindgen]
pub fn greet_async(f: &js_sys::Function) {
    let this = JsValue::null();
    let _ = f.call1(&this, &JsValue::from_str("Hello world"));
}
```

**example-project/webpack.config.js**:

```js
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    watch: true,
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'index.js'
    },
    experiments: {
        asyncWebAssembly: true
    }
};
```

**example-project/index.html**:

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="./dist/index.js"></script> <!-- this is the bundled version of index.js from above -->
</head>
<body>
    <div>Hello there.</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there a reference in your code or in a dependency called `heap`?  It looks like something isn't being initialized correctly.  There is an open bug report to wasm-bindgen which seems to be related to webpack5, but I'm not sure if your issue is the same.  https://github.com/rustwasm/wasm-bindgen/issues/2343

Comment: I added the `wasm-pack` generated code where it's being referenced in my question. Could it be an issue with wasm-pack & webpack 5?